# My Volley class uses outdated Shared Preferences value

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, sharedpreferences, android-volley

I have a Volley constructor class:

```
class VolleySingleton constructor(context: Context) {
    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: VolleySingleton? = null

        fun getInstance(context: Context) =
            INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                INSTANCE ?: VolleySingleton(context).also {
                    INSTANCE = it
                }
            }
    }

   some deals..
}
```

I use Shared Preferences value to compare hosts in custom hostnameVerifier:

```
private val sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
private val expectedHost: String? = sharedPref.getString("expectedHostname", null)

private val hostnameVerifier: HostnameVerifier = HostnameVerifier { _, session ->
    val hv = HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier()
    hv.verify(expectedHost, session)
}
```

When I change value of *expectedHostname* in my SettingsActivity it's get immediately updated in MainActivity as I can see with Log.d but not in class VolleySingleton. It still has previous value. Only restart of app solves the problem.

New instance of class I create in MainActivity the way like this:

```
VolleySingleton.getInstance(applicationContext).addToRequestQueue(request)
```

I'm very new in Kotlin and Java and will appreciate any help with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sharedPref.getString("expectedHostname", null)` value is computed once and saved in the `expectedHost` backing field when the `VolleySingleton` object gets initialized. If you want to return a different, updated value on every time `expectedHost` is called, you have to move the proper logic to the property's getter:

```
private val expectedHost: String?
    get() = sharedPref.getString("expectedHostname", null)
```

Comment: Thanks bro! Could you clear one more thing for me please? I added one question to the update section.

Comment: @Hitchman Is `getSocketFactory()` supposed to return a different `SSLSocketFactory` instance based on the `hostnameVerifier` value?

Comment: @Hitchman Unfortunately I'm not familiar with Volley and `HttpStack` related classes enough. You may try to save a reference to the `httpsURLConnection` object, set an [`OnSharedPreferenecesChangeListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener), listen on the `expectedHostname` value updates and change the `httpsURLConnection.hostnameVerifier` when the setting gets changed. However I'm only guessing this could work.